# Complex numbers and linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, complex-numbers

I got this assignment where I have linked list with Complex numbers and the task is to imput and print these numbers with help of linked list. Several years ago i studied the basics of complex numbers but the assignment is really confusing for me now and I don't know where to start, the only given information is the one above and the following .h file:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
#include <iostream>
struct Complex
{
  int real, imag;
};
void read(Complex &, std::istream &);
void print(const Complex &, std::ostream & os=std::cout);
bool operator<(const Complex & lhs, const Complex & rhs);
bool operator>(const Complex & lhs, const Complex & rhs);
bool operator==(const Complex & lhs, const Complex & rhs);

#endif
```

I would be rally thankful for some initial guidance with this assignment, what should the print and read functons contain (except the given arguments) in order to use?? bool operators above? I googled for couple of hours but could not find any good relevance between complex numbers tutorials and my task, furthermore i have deadline for this and contacting my teachers with questions about this will take days.

Comment: A complex type using `int` instead of `double` and which defines an ordering relation seems to quite odd... However, the read function would just read two `int`s and, when successful, set the corresponding fields. The print function would just print the members. What exactly is your problem with that?

Comment: well, it is just confusing for men, but thanks for the guidance, i will try to implement it

Comment: I don't see how a linked list plays into this assignment at all, given the definitions/delcarations given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print function should display the number on the indicated output stream. Conventionally, complex numbers are displayed like this: `1+2i` or this: `(1+2i)` or even this: `(1,2)`. You might accomplish this through operator chaining:

```
os << "(" << c.real << "+" << c.imag << "i)";
```

The equality check should return true if both components of `lhs` are equal to their counterparts in `rhs`:

```
return lhs.real == rhs.real && lhs.imag == rhs.imag;
```

The details of `read`, `operator<` and `operator>` will vary according to your exact assignment. Re-read your assignment, paying close attention to any definition of what those functions are required to do.

Comment: thanks, how should i proceed with the print function, it is a bit confusing without -> next pointer in these nodes